# How to add script in pom.xml to uninstall rpm without deletes war file

Tags: rpm, pom.xml

I have a project P to create a rpm A. A contains a same war file, shared.war, with rpm B. Can I add some script in P'pom.xml to check if B installed in the system, shared.war will not be deleted during uninstalling A?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you configured the rpm in the same module than the war? If yes that's the wrong way....make separate projects for rpm and war where rpm use the war as dedendency.

Comment: The war file is in a separate project than A and B. I add the dependency in A and B.

Comment: If you are working with a RPM you have to have a uninstall script inside the RPM...which does the job...

Answer (score 2):

If you use rpm's then I understand you could place shared.war in a separate rpm package that both A and B would require.